# Android Custom View With Scale Anim

Tags: android, user-interface

I draw a circle in a custom view, the circle become larger when clicked, how should I do it with anim.

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ScaleAnimation`

```
public void scaleView(View v,float xxScaleValue,float yScaleValue) {
    Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(
            1f, xScaleValue, //  for the X axis scaling
            1f, yScaleValue) // for the Y axis scaling
    anim.setFillAfter(true); // Needed to keep the result of the animation
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

And in your Activity call

```
scaleView(yourview,2f,2f); //your own scaling values
```